# What do you do when you print job won't cancel?

Tags: windows, printing

I'm trying to cancel a print job in Vista to an HP 3845.  I've rebooted, but it's still there, with Status "Deleting - Printing" thought nothing is happening.

How can I make it really go away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is really serious you can restart the Windows Printing Service under the Services MMC. What I normally find with the HP the following steps fixes it.

- Switch off the printer
- Delete the job
- Restart the Printing Service
- Restart the printer

Sometimes however the restart requires a complete machine restart.

Comment: My suggestion when i read the question was to stop and restart the print spooler service.

Comment: I'm accepting this based on your comment under my answer.  Nevertheless, I'll mention that this printer has only two buttons, and neither were shutting it down.

Comment: If you know which folder you have set to store spool files then (you can find it in the print server properties window from the printers and faxes window) you can manually delete the spool files once you've stopped the print spooler service

Comment: @Diago: Sometimes restarting the spooler doesn't always work. As Col mentioned, sometimes it's necessary to trash the files in the print spooler folder.

Comment: It's amazing that in 2010 we still have to reboot to cancel a print job.

Answer (score 6):

- start
- run
- services.msc
- Find the printspooler service
- restart this service
- Fix missing paper / wrong port / any problem...
- print again

Comment: Only works for an administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of these suggestions did it, but unplugging the printer, and then plugging it back in did the job.

Comment: I've had this issue alot in the past, and there is some sort of shared queue between the user/pc printing and the printer the job is sent too. The best/fastest way I've found is to reboot both PC and printer. I'm glad you managed to answer your own question :)

Comment: If it was switched on and off correctly it would have had the same effect as plugging it in and out.

Comment: Neither switching off nor unplugging helped in my case. But, cancelling in the queue has helped.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the print spool service go to local disk>windows>System32>spool>PRINTERS and delete all the files here then restart the spool service and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just wait until it goes away.

If the print job already is in the printer (meaning, the printer keeps printing), I usually take the paper from the printer, and switch it off **after it stops printing**.
Switching off a printer while printing usually is not a good idea, leads to paper jam.

Comment: The emphasis on the paper jam sounds like a traumatic sysadmin experience.

Answer (score 0):

What Donald said...deleting all files in the PRINTERS directory *usually* clears this up.

Failing that, try this fix from MS:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000007

Answer (score 0):

Save the following in a .CMD file and run that file (Run as Admin if using Windows Vista, 7 or later) every time you want to cancel a print job:

`net stop spooler`
`del %systemroot%\system32\spool\printers*.shd`
`del %systemroot%\system32\spool\printers*.spl`
`net start spooler`

([Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/12w0k1/reddit_can_you_name_one_thing_that_is_and_will/c6ypkjd))